# undeclared identifier when trying to install libsodium-php on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: libsodium

I'm having some trouble installing the php wrapper for libsodium on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed libsodium with `sudo apt-get install libsodium` but when I run `sudo pecl install libsodium` I get a undeclared identifier error.

```
    running: make
    /bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root1K2CoA/libsodium-2.0.1/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/libsodium -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root1K2CoA/libsodium-2.0.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root1K2CoA/libsodium-2.0.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/libsodium -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/libsodium/libsodium.c -o libsodium.lo
    libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/libsodium -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root1K2CoA/libsodium-2.0.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root1K2CoA/libsodium-2.0.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/libsodium -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/libsodium/libsodium.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libsodium.o
    /tmp/pear/temp/libsodium/libsodium.c: In function ‘zif_sodium_crypto_kdf_derive_from_key’:
    /tmp/pear/temp/libsodium/libsodium.c:2899:29: error: ‘crypto_kdf_blake2b_CONTEXTBYTES’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         memcpy(ctx_padded, ctx, crypto_kdf_blake2b_CONTEXTBYTES);
                                 ^
    /tmp/pear/temp/libsodium/libsodium.c:2899:29: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    Makefile:194: recipe for target 'libsodium.lo' failed
    make: *** [libsodium.lo] Error 1
    ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: Consider asking this quesiton on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like apt-get wasn't installing the latest version of libsodium. After downloading and compiling the latest version I was able to install the php extension.